# Are there any relations between perverse t-structure (cohomologies) and standard t-structure (cohomologies)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, perverse-sheaves, t-structure

I'm reading the Corollary 3.2.3. in [Exponential motives](http://javier.fresan.perso.math.cnrs.fr/expmot.pdf) by J. Fresan and P. Jossen.

The authors use the following statement in the proof of Corollary 3.2.3: let $C$ be any object in the derived category of constructible sheaves over complex plane. We denote by $^p\mathcal{H}^n$ the perverse cohomology sheaf, and $\mathcal{H}^n$ the usual cohomology sheaf. Then we always have

$${ }^p \mathcal{H}^n(\Pi(C)) \cong \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\Pi(C))[1] $$
where $\Pi$ is the projector. Here $\Pi$ is an endofunctor on the derived category of perverse sheaves. It's exact for perverse t-structure and takes $\mathbf{Perv}$ to $\mathbf{Perv}_0$.
How does this equality hold?

Remark: as [pointed out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466187/are-there-any-relations-between-perverse-t-structure-cohomologies-and-standard#comment1209476_466187) by R.van Dobben de Bruyn that it's not true in general that $$\mathcal{H}^0( ^p\mathcal{H}^0 C) = \mathcal{H}^0(C),$$
by considering the case when $C$ is a local system.

Or are there any concrete descriptions of the truncation functors $\tau^{\leq 0}$ for the perverse t-structure? Any references will be appreciated.

Comment: ... and P. Jossen.

Comment: Hmm, isn't it the case that if $C$ is a locally constant sheaf (placed in degree 0), then viewed as a complex of perverse sheaves it lives in degree 1 (i.e. $C[1]$ is a perverse sheaf, so that $C$ is $P[-1]$ for a perverse sheaf $P$), so its $^p\mathcal H^0$ vanishes? Yet its classical $\mathcal H^0$ is just $C$ itself.

Comment: Thanks, R.van Dobben de Bruyn. You are right on the counterexample. Then the author must use some other argument

Comment: Thank you, Oli, for the reminder!

Comment: They explain this in the paper, don't they? Their first isomorphism is t-exactness of $\Pi$, and the second follows from the characterisation (Lemma 2.3.3) that $\Pi(C) = F[1]$ for $F$ a classical sheaf (i.e. $H^i(F) = 0$ except when $i = 0$).

Comment: That's correct. However, the assertion that $F = \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\Pi (C))$ remains unclear. Initially, we only know that $F= \mathcal{H}^{-1}(^p\mathcal{H}^n(\Pi(C)))$.